# How to prevent extra-planar telecomunication

Tags: dnd-3.5e, paladin, antipaladin

I am a ex-paladin in my campaign. His god/demons are tempting him in the hopes of a new zealous fighter. I am looking for a way to stop these powers from communicating with my character directly.

The communication typically goes through an artifact, religious or otherwise.

The character is low level.

Comment: Do you know *how* these creatures are communicating with the ex-paladin? Is it through a spell like [*dream*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsDtoE.html#dream) or [*sending*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsS.html#sending), or is the means more complicated, like DM fiat? (Given the variety of possible means of communication, it might be impossible to answer this without more details.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan typically the communication is through religious artifacts. For example, I encountered a Pelor Chalice which Pelor communicated telepathically with me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the spell(s) *Consecrate*/*Desecrate*.  They're one of the only ways to outright prevent direct divine intervention.  The relevant passage is in the spell description, and states:

> If the area does contain an altar, shrine, or other permanent fixture of a deity, pantheon, or higher power other than your patron, the consecrate spell instead curses the area, cutting off its connection with the associated deity or power.

So you'll need a shrine/altar for each diety/demon/whatever you want to block out, but this should be a foolproof shield against such meddling otherwise, provided you can keep the effect up indefinitely.  You can do this with enough money via the *Incense of Consecration* from the Book of Exalted Deeds which grants you a mobile *Consecrate* effect at 300 gp per 6 hours per god.

You can also do it for free if you are a Sacred Exorcist of at least 5th level, but it is unlikely that you will be able to meet the prerequisites of that class as a fallen paladin if you have not already entered it.

Comment: The Consecrate/Desecrate spell would be what I need, I am just going to keep the post active for any other options that would last longer than 6 hours.

Comment: "cutting off its connection" is more vague than you're giving it credit for.  If the deity is limited to communication only via these "connections", your solution would work, but not if the deity is more powerful and/or willing to devote power to transmit messages to this PC.

Comment: It only cuts off the connection "If the area does contain an altar, shrine, or other permanent fixture of a deity, pantheon, or higher power other than your patron," so if your patron is the one badgering you to become a zealot, then this won't work.

Comment: @Carrara Simple solution: stop worshipping said deity.

Answer (score 3):

Cheaper than the incense of consecration would be a wand of consecrate at CL3. Incense costs 300gp per 6hr use, or 50gp/hr. A CL3 wand of consecrate would cost 4500gp, but would last for 50 6hr uses, or only 15gp/hr. Do you want a longer-lasting effect? Get a higher caster level. A CL5 wand lasts for 10hr/cast. It costs more, but it's still the flat 15gp/hr rate. Look to metamagic.

The downside of a wand, however, is that it's a spell trigger item, not a wondrous item. So the effect of the consecrate/desecrate doesn't move with you. Wands are better for downtime, when you know you'll be staying in one place for a while, i.e. you can consecrate the inside of a rope trick to have unassailable shelter, insulated from gods and mortals alike (unless they want to hunt around on the astral plane).

The long-term option is just to get a permanent item enchanted with a consecrate effect. For 12,000gp, you can get consecrate as a continuous spell effect on, say, a shiny rock you hold when you're not holding your weapon.

This rock, though, will only effect it and the 20ft around it. Do you want a bigger range? A CL rock of widened consecrate will run you for 90,000gp, but will have a 40ft radius. Personally, I wouldn't recommend it.

You can tie the 20ft shiny rocks of consecrate to crossbow bolts, and for 1000gp, you can get a CL1 shiny rock of launch bolt. With that, you can toss around four 20ft-radius consecrated zones for a fraction of the cost of a single 40ft rock.

Comment: While I will most likely use your shiny rock idea, the consecrate spell was given in the first answer and your solutions are all based on it.

Comment: You should point out that the permanent item you mention is built using the Custom Magic Item Price Estimation rules, which only provide an estimate as to the gp cost for an item and might be quite off target.  I don't know that they are off target in this case, but some analysis would  be needed.  Also you forgot to include the 100X the cost of material components thing, and possibly the X4 cost for being slotless (though if you meant to have it take a 'weapon' slot, that works). The actual slotless cost estimate would be 74,000 gp. 62,000 gp instead if it has to be held.